# Adding a 3rd Monitor to my HP pavilion g7

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I currently have a HP pavilion g7 laptop with a samsung 17" monitor plugged in via a RGB port. I am currently considering purchasing another screen so that i can run 3 screens in total. If i purchased a usb screen would this allow me to run all 3 screens at once? Does my laptop have the processing power to handle this load?

Comment: We have no idea if your laptop has enough processing power to handle the load because we know nothing about your laptop.  There are 4 different versions of the G7 3 of the 4 versions are low quality junk.  It also entirel depends what you wish to push onto the monitor itself.

Comment: many low end laptops cannot do three displays, their videochips simply do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to run multiple monitors with USB adapters.  I have not tried USBv3 versions of these adapters, but they would definitely be the way to go.  Here is an [example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007L6NYAO) of a USBv3 adapter.   USBv2 worked fine, but their was very noticeable latency on the display.  USBv2 would not be acceptable for games or movies, but for simple browsing and spreadsheets, etc its fine.  You have 2 USBv3 ports on your laptop, so I would spring for the extra cost of the v3 adapters.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. thats exactly what i would like to use it for spreadsheets, trading platforms etc. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run 2 external monitors plus the internal monitor of your G7. i am running 2 HP w1707  and the internal monitor at once without any dock or any 3rd party software or hardware add ons. but i also am using windows 10. i have my external monitors connected to the vga output and hdmi output. i first configured only using 2 of the 3 monitors. i configure my hdmi output as main display and then extended my desktop to the vga output monitor. when doing that the internal monitors goes black.i then closed out display settings then open up windows 10 multiview and extended my display again to internal monitor. so my desktop is extended 3 times. ao from left to right when i hit identify monitors i have the 2,1,3.My desktop is extended over 3 monitors.it is possible without using any 3rd party add ons to run 3 monitors on G7. dont know about windows 7 or windows 8, but it definitely works with windows 10